# SQLite + EF 6 ошибка таблиц

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6

```
  <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite"  type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
</providers>



  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
  </DbProviderFactories>

 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\CoffeeShop.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
```

```
    namespace WpfApp1.Models
{
    class DatesContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatesContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Day> DateSet { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Drink> DrinkSet { get; set; }

    }

    class Day 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Drink_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }



    }
      public class Drink 
    { 
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        db = new DatesContext();


        db.DateSet.Load();
    }
```

Пишет что нет таких таблиц  Days,Drinks

Comment: Положите вашу БД рядом с EXE файлом. Например, в папку Bin\Debug

Comment: @tym32167 Лучший, оперативно и качественно)